# How to remove port number in nginx when redirecting

Tags: nginx

This is my `domain.conf` file in nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 8080;
    server_name EXAMPLE.COM www.EXAMPLE.COM;
    return 301 https://EXAMPLE.COM$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    root /home/path;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/EXAMPLE.COM/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.IO Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Now when I type `http://EXAMPLE.COM:8080` or `http://EXAMPLE.COM:8080/some_folder/`, my website over the port number 8080 works, but I want to remove this port number.

But what I want is:

--> Whenever I type `http://EXAMPLE.COM:8080/folder`, it redirects to `https://EXAMPLE.COM/folder`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer of what you are looking for is in proxy_redirect option, after proxy_pass.

This nginx configuration sample can be useful: (Take a look on proxy redirect line)

```
location /one/ {

proxy_pass     http://upstream:port/two/;

proxy_redirect http://upstream:port/two/ /one/;
```

I think adding this should do the trick:

```
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8000 /blog;
```

You can find full documentation and examples in the nginx documentation.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Comment: I tried that and read the docs but they did not work. I'm not sure whether it should be a `proxy_redirect` or other thing